# Taking on additional responsibility during difficult times

Tags: networking, personal-problems

Tonight my boss wants me to go to a networking event, he is aware that I have recently broken up with my GF and I have told him today that I don't feel as though I am in the frame of mind to network heavily. Networking, and going to events is beyond my job description by the way, so it is an additional duty given that is outside of working hours too and unpaid.

He just told me, that he is not going to force me and that it is up to me, but at the same time talking about the benefits of going for the company. I can tell that he wants me to go anyway. So to avoid rocking the boat, I have agreed to do it to show him that despite my problems I am a dedicated and loyal employee. The real reason however for going is that I am worried that if I don't he may one day use this as an example for how my personal life has affected my productivity.

Have I made the right decision? I am also starting to regret bringing it up, in case he starts scrutinising my performance at work.

Comment: Ok, I won't mention anything about it again. My boss figured this out a few weeks ago, and has taken an active interest.

Comment: Are you salaried or hourly?

Comment: @MaskedMan That really depends on the work environment. In smaller companies, it's not at all unusual to spend time with your colleagues during your lunchbreak etc. Over time, you're bound to pick up some basic private information about your colleagues (such as who's married or has kids). If the boss joins in on these occasions, he'll know (almost) as much as the rest of OP's colleagues.

Comment: Even in bigger companies, unless you never ever have conversations with anyone, then it's bound to come up sometimes.

Comment: Also, if you expect some level of accommodation from your boss/employer when there is an issue with your GF, spouse, children,...They probably want to know they exist beforehand.

Comment: @Llewellyn Ok, and how would they pick up that information if you don't share it? In my experience, it is more common for people to keep showboating about their relationship irritating colleagues to no end, and then the same people whine about invasion of privacy when a colleague, especially a boss, takes too much interest in their private life.

Comment: @Llewellyn is correct, I work in a start up, it is very difficult to keep your professional and personal life seperate since I spend a lot of time with my boss (and the team) during lunch breaks etc Being middle management means that I generally work very closely with him.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All voluntary work events are mandatory.  Not to be harsh or unfeeling, but you don't want to damage your career.  You made the right  decision. Be confident, enjoy yourself and press on.  Who knows, you may even network with someone outside of business reasons.

Comment: Also, It's probably a better idea to allow yourself to be busy rather than focus on your sorrows, alone. Sure, the latter is unavoidable but trying to keep busy is definitely a way to forget and get over things. Good luck!

Comment: Vluntary work events are mandatory? I don't get it.

Comment: @WorkerDrone if you don't go to a "voluntary" event, you'll kill your career.

Comment: At the risk of appearing to be insensitive to your loss, I must point out that conferences and networking events are excellent opportunities to engage new people, expand your social circle, and develop a new emotional life that will eventually eclipse your current pain. - Plus, there are sure to be be eligible women there.

Comment: re: "All voluntary work events are mandatory" I think that varies greatly depending on the job, field, level, etc.

It's a good rule of thumb but it's probably always a hard requirement.

Comment: @RichardU I see what you mean now. That doesn't happen where I work.

Comment: @WorkerDrone it varies from place to place, but while it never hurts to go, it can if you don't.  Also.... Charity drives.  contribute now or pay later

Comment: @RichardU if you want to have a life, it hurts to go.

Comment: @WorkerDrone in Japan maybe, but work functions are infrequent elsewhere

Comment: yep voluntary = you better do it or you're hurting yourself

Comment: Turned out to be the right move, ended up meeting interesting people, the most interesting was somebody who worked for Mashable. Told my boss, he just told me 'you see, it was worth it'

Answer (score 6):

I see two things here:

### 1. This is an extra task

This task is not included in your job description, outside your normal working hours and unpaid. You have a good reason to decline it as it is not what you're hired to do.

Whether that is a good idea in the long term depends on your position within the company, company culture and your industry (e.g. some roles tend to have a lot of networking events and meet new people often).

### 2. Your personal events are affecting your work

While it is irrational to expect everyone to act like machines (we're humans anyway), a reasonable amount of professionalism is expected. Depending on personality, this may not be easy. Events such as the death of a dear friend or a divorce can and do severely affect one's productivity.

If you need time to quiet down, you can ask for a day or two holiday. You do not have to state the reason to anyone at the workplace. Just simply say you wish a day off.

### Combining the two

Next time, you can simply reply "I'm not available on that evening". If somebody asks why, simply said "I have other activities after work" or "I have going out with a friend" or something similar. If your relationship with the others at the workplace is purely professional and not personal, there is no need to mention personal events to anyone.